# dependency of objects in java

Tags: java, object, architecture, dependencies

When does one object depend on another?

If class A creates or uses object B, then A depends on B - it needs it to work with, to fulfill maybe some task.

But B depends also on A, its created or used by it.

So is dependency in java circular?

Comment: It depends on what context you're using the word "depends" - it sounds like you have a specific, technical context in mind but to my mind there's no single unambiguous definition.

Comment: hm, I mean "depend" like: a relation between two classes. Maybe these are two different things. One is: "The Class A cant fulfill its task without Object B, it NEEDS it, it really 'depends' on it". The other is: "Object B is USED by Class A, so there is a 'inextricable' relation between them". Maybe there is another word for the second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition is circular however Java's references only go one way.

Dependencies only go from Object that has a need to Objects which provided that need.  You can have circular dependencies.  You can't talk about a need to be needed for Objects. I think that only applies to people (and possibly pets). ;)

Comment: I might feed my dog, but I require petting him.  +1 from me.

Comment: I was thinking of dogs in the need to needed category.  That's because we believe they have complex emotions. ;)

Comment: "You can't talk about a need to be needed for Objects" haha, sounds correct :-) Did you read my comment in my own posting? Maybe my picture of "dependency" is/was wrong. Of course Object B doesnt have a need to be needed and therefor not generally depend on other classes. but when it is USED by another class, there is somehow a relation between them, right? maybe not a "dependency" - but when the object B is used by class A, it is really tied to class A. I thought of this like a dependency.

Comment: When A uses B, A depends on B.  B depends on A to exist and possibly to continue to exist, but this is not the sort of dependency that is interesting or what people generally refer to.

Comment: "When A uses B, A depends on B. B depends on A to exist and possibly to continue to exist." ok, correct. 

"but this is not the sort of dependency that is interesting or what people generally refer to" they might not refer to it, correct too, but it _is_ really interesting - at least for myself :-) thank you for helping to clarify it!

Answer (score 1):

Circular dependencies are possible, but they only happen when you have references in both objects:

```
public class A
{
    private List<B> children;
}

public class B
{
    private A parent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes if A depends on B and B depends on A then its circular dependency

Answer (score 0):

The *dependency graph* has a circle. The *dependencies* themselves are unidirectional.